# Coq constructor can't take two arguments of different types?

Tags: coq

I am just getting started with Coq and am confused as to why this isn't allowed.

```
Inductive prod: Type :=
| pair (n1: nat n2: bool).
```

I get a "The reference n2 was not found in the current
environment" complaint.

When I make both arguments nats, or both arguments bools, like this

`Inductive prod: Type :=
 | pair (n1 n2: bool).`

it doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In between one set of parentheses you can only have arguments of one type.

```
Inductive prod : Type :=
| pair (x y : bool).
```

But you cannot indeed have several types, the syntax for it is to use several sets of brackets:

```
Inductive prod : Type :=
| pair (x : nat) (y : bool).
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: If that answers your question, you tick it as accepted so people know you're not looking for more answers.